# Are comments considered publications

Tags: publications, journals, citations

The journal Science has two sections for submission, Research articles and Commentary.
http://www.sciencemag.org/site/feature/contribinfo/prep/gen_info.xhtml

Under commentary, there is a section for 'Policy Forum'.  Unlike 'Education Forum' there is nothing explicit about research related to Policy.  If one submits (not invited) a manuscript to Policy Forum, is this considered peer reviewed publication? Is there a difference in citation both in format of a citation and if it is common to cite a manuscript published in Commentary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general discussion for the Commentary section mentions this:

> Commentary material may be peer-reviewed at the Editors' discretion.

If you look up a sample Policy Forum paper online, you can download the [citation information](http://www.sciencemag.org/citmgr?gca=sci%3B296%2F5568%2F659). For example,

```
NUCLEAR WASTE  
Yucca Mountain  
Rodney C. Ewing and Allison Macfarlane 
Science 26 April 2002:  296 (5568), 659-660. [DOI:10.1126/science.1071886]
```

and then in various formats. Here's the BibTeX entry:

```
@article{Ewing26042002,
author = {Ewing, Rodney C. and Macfarlane, Allison}, 
title = {Yucca Mountain},
volume = {296}, 
number = {5568}, 
pages = {659-660}, 
year = {2002}, 
doi = {10.1126/science.1071886}, 
URL = {http://www.sciencemag.org/content/296/5568/659.short}, 
eprint = {http://www.sciencemag.org/content/296/5568/659.full.pdf}, 
journal = {Science} 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In general, a "Comment" is always a publication. However, your question is whether it should be listed in someone's publication list, presumably along side peer-reviewed articles. I believe the relevant criterion, as *mkennedy* suggests, is if the comment has itself been peer-reviewed. When yes, it can go in the regular list; if not, then it should presumably be relegated to a "additional publications" list or something of that type.